# Monotonicity And Riemann Integration

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f(x)$ is a monotonic function on the interval $[a,b]$ then $f(x)$ is Riemann Integrable on the interval $[a, b]$. Now for any $x$, $y$ member of $[a, b]$ we have $f(x)$ monotonic on the interval $[x, y]$and hence Riemann Integrable on $[x, y]$. Let $$I=\int^y_xf(x)dx$$.
Now for any given $\epsilon>0$ we can make the difference $U-I<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ where $U$ means the upper sum of $f(x)$ on the interval $[x, y]$ by making the mesh size less than $\delta$. Now if we choose a partition of $[x, y]$ with equal subintervals and size of each sub interval is $(\delta)_0<\delta$ and $(\delta)_0<1$ then $U-L<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, Similarly we can make the difference $I-L<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ And hence adding both the inequalities we get $$U-L<\epsilon$$ Now as the function is monotonic on the interval $[x, y]$ and the partition was into equal sub intervals $(\delta)_0$ So $$U-L=(f(y)-f(x))(\delta)_0$$ And hence $$(f(y)-f(x))(\delta)_0<(\epsilon)((\delta)_0)<\epsilon$$ as $(\delta)_0<1$ And so we can make $f(y)-f(x)<\epsilon$ for any $x$ and $y$ and so $f(x)$ must be uniformly continuous but is is not true always So where is the fault in the above reasoning.
$$$$ Can anyone plz help me$$$$

Comment: Doesn’t $\delta_0$ depend on $x$ and $y$?

Comment: ${\delta}_0$ only depends upon $\delta$

Comment: Try taking a specific discontinuous monotonic function and a specific epsilon showing that it's discontinuous and see where things go wrong.

Comment: Can you plz give full explanation

Comment: But $\delta$ depends on $x$ and $y$, so $\delta_0$ does too

Comment: But what does it imply??

Comment: I want to know that what is the fault in the above reasoning